Did George Pólya actually invent Pólya's Urn?
This is something I have wondered about for a while, but did Pólya actually invent Pólya's Urn?

The Pólya Urn problem can be stated as follows:
At time $t=0$, an urn contains $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls. At
each time step $t \geq 1$:

Draw one ball randomly from the urn
Return the drawn ball plus one additional ball of the same color

Let $X_t$ be the proportion of black balls at time $t$. Then:
$$X_t = \frac{\text{number of black balls at time }t}{\text{total
> number of balls at time }t} = \frac{B_t}{B_t + W_t}$$
where $B_t$ and $W_t$ represent the number of black and white balls at
time $t$ respectively.
The transition probabilities at each step are:
$$P(B_{t+1} = B_t + 1 | B_t, W_t) = \frac{B_t}{B_t + W_t}$$
$$P(W_{t+1} = W_t + 1 | B_t, W_t) = \frac{W_t}{B_t + W_t}$$

I have never seen a direct reference which shows that he invented/popularized the Pólya Urn Problem. Is this something that was just attributed to him posthumously?

Polya did not invent urn models generally, they go back to Bernoulli and are used in Whitworth's text Choice and Chance (1901), for example. He did, together with Eggenberger, consider a class of models with multiple replacement that now bear his/their name in Über die Statistik verketteter Vorgänge (1923), although that too was done before them by Markov (A generalization of a problem on a sequential exchange of balls, Collected Works, p. 589, presented at a meeting of Physico-Mathematical
Section of the Academy of Sciences, October 8, 1917). Markov wrote in Russian, so presumably most Western mathematicians took these models from Eggenberger-Polya. Here is a historical note from Johnson-Kotz, Urn Models and Their Application:

"The development of these methods stems largely from a paper by Eggenberger and Polya (1923): and the distributions as a group are known as Polya's distributions. (There are differences in usage among different authors.) The common feature of all these methods is that sampling with some form
of replacement is used, but this is not simple replacement of the ball last chosen. The way in which the replacement is modified determines the particular subclass of distributions arising. In particular, the kind of replacement depends on the results of the sampling. Eggenberger and Polya (1923) supposed that an urn containing balls of
two colors - say white and black - is used, and after each drawing, the chosen ball is returned, together with $s$ balls of the same color. 
Markov (1906) considered this problem (with $s = 1$) and (with general $s > 0$) in Markov (1917), and for this reason his name is coupled with Polya's by some authors (e.g., Janardan and Schaeffer, 1975; Stancu, 1970a). (It appears, however, that the triple Markov-Eggenberger-Polya is not used.) Also, a similar model has been proposed by Brillouin (1927). As pointed out by Frechet (1943), this model with $s = 1$ was also considered by Chuprov before the appearance of the Eggenberger-Polya (1923) paper. He presumably
refers to Tschuprov (1922)."


thank you for your answer! So Polya popularized a version of these problems?

@konofoso Polya did publish on related problems later, e.g. in Eine Wahrscheinlichkeitsaufgabe in der Kundenwerbung (1930) and Sur quelques points de la théorie des probabilités (1931), he was a superb expositor and subsequent authors cite his papers, so one could say that he popularized them.

Re "Markov wrote in Russian" I am not sure whether it covers material relevant to the context at hand, but Eggenberger's Ph.D. thesis cites the German translation of a work on probability calculus by Markov: "A. Markoff: Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung. Übersetzt von Liebmann. Leipzig 1912."

@njuffa  Johnson-Kotz cite Markov's 1906 and 1917 works on urn models, they are both in Russian. But yes, he published works in German and French also. Chuprov's is in a somewhat obscure Scandinavian journal that was founded in the year of his publication, 1922.

F. Eggenberger and G. Pólya, "Über die Statistik verketteter Vorgänge."
Zeitschrift für Angewandte Mathematik und Mechanik, Vol. 3, No. 4, Aug. 1923, pp. 279-289.
Florian Eggenberger was a Ph.D. student of Pólya whose 1924 Ph.D. thesis on a topic in statistics ("Die Wahrscheinlichkeitsansteckung -- ein Beitrag zur theoretischen Statistik") was examined by George Pólya and Hermann Weyl.
ZAMM is a journal focused on applied mathematics and mechanics, which at that time was published by the press of the Verein Deutscher Ingenieure, the largest engineering association in Germany. Section 4 of the paper discusses applications to epidemiology and uses statistics on deaths from smallpox in Switzerland between 1877 and 1900 as a concrete example.
Richard von Mises was editor-in-chief of ZAMM at the time and appears to have corresponded with Pólya on an ongoing basis. In a letter dated December 15, 1922 he commented positively on Pólya's manuscript that he had just received but proposed a new title. One motivation was to put more emphasis on the applied aspects in keeping with the thematic nature of the journal. Von Mises's suggested title is the one used for the published version [1]. Subsequently, von Mises appears to have popularized Pólya's urn model in his book
Richard von Mises, Wahrscheinlichkeit Statistik und Wahrheit. Vienna: Julius Springer 1928.
On p. 109 he introduces Pólya's urn model and presents the same example of deaths from smallpox in Switzerland that Eggenberger and Pólya used in the original paper:

[...] G. Pólya hat uns kürzlich gezeigt, wie man dieses Problem mit den Hilfsmitteln der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung in eleganter Weise behandeln kann.
[...]
Für eine Statistik "mit Ansteckung" trifft dieses Bild nicht mehr zu. Hier werden offenbar durch Eintritt eines Todesfalls die Aussichten, daß weitere eintreten, verstärkt. Man kann nach Pólya diesem Umstand in dem Bild -- man sagt hiefür auch oft: in dem "Urnenschema" --  dadurch Rechnung tragen, daß man annimmt: So oft eine schwarze Kugel gezogen ist, wird nicht nur diese zurückgelegt, sondern es werden die Kugeln in der Urne um eine bestimmte Zahl schwarzer Kugeln vermehrt. Auf diese Weise hat man es nicht mehr mit einem einzigen Ausgangskollektiv zu tun, sondern mit einer Reihe verschiedener, deren Verteilungen man aber genau kennt, nämlich mit Urnen von verschiedenen Füllungen.


[1] Reinhard Siegmund-Schultze, "Probability in 1919/20: the von Mises-Pólya-Controversy." Archive for History of Exact Sciences, Vol. 60, 2006, pp. 431-515.
